# Convex hull: $n+1$ points suffice in dimension $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-hulls

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The convex hull of $S$ is defined to be

$$
\left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i x_i \mid k \in \mathbb{N}, x_i \in S, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}, \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i = 1 \right\rbrace.
$$

It feels intuitively clear to me that one should be able to replace this by

$$
\left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lambda_i x_i \mid  x_i \in S, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}, \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lambda_i = 1 \right\rbrace,
$$
that is, that every point in the convex hull can actually be written as the convex combination of some $n+1$ points from the original set (depending on the chosen point of course). Is there a short argument for this?

Comment: Use a similar argument for showing that any linear basis has exactly $n$ elements in a finite-dimensional space - except here for the convex hull, we talk about affine independence.

Comment: My problem is that with the convex hull - as opposed to the affine hull - the coefficients $\lambda_i$ are required to be positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Carathéodory's theorem. 
[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)) has a short argument.

Comment: Sometimes all you need is someone to point the way. Thanks!